# Create a "final" filter in an UNION SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several queries united for UNION clauses
I want to filter the total result from one field.
One idea is to filter every query, but it could be "hard" work for nothing.

```
SELECT 'GROUP1' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP2' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP3' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE

--WHERE LicenseCode > 7878
```

Obviously, the final statement doesn't work. 
How can I filter the total UNION result? (without to put the statement (`WHERE LicenseCode > 7878`) in every query.

Thanks!
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the union a subquery and then filter the result:

```
select group, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
from (
  SELECT 'GROUP1' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
  FROM TABLE
  UNION
  SELECT 'GROUP2' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
  FROM TABLE
  UNION
  SELECT 'GROUP3' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
  FROM TABLE
) x
WHERE LicenseCode > 7878
```

Comment: You may need an alias for the derived table in SQL Server.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Possibly... so added just in case.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Exactly. I have had to put an alias to say "WHERE totalgroup.LicenseCode > 7878"

Answer (score 7):

First, don't use `UNION`, use `UNION ALL`.  `UNION` incurs additional overhead for removing duplicates.

Second, the answer to your question is to use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ((SELECT 'GROUP1' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
       FROM TABLE
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'GROUP2' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
       FROM TABLE
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'GROUP3' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
       FROM TABLE
      )
     ) t
WHERE LicenseCode > 7878;
```

SQL Server has a smart optimizer.  I'm pretty sure that it pushes the `WHERE` clause down to the individual subqueries.  This is an important optimization.  In databases that don't do that, you would want to repeat the `WHERE` condition.

Note:  If you are selecting from the same table then there is a better way to write the query:

```
select grp, t.licensecode, t.field2, t.field3, t.field4
from table t cross apply
     (values ('group1'), ('group2'), ('group3')) g(grp)
where licensecode > 7878;
```

Comment: I am not sure. But if you are using a different 'GROUP' (GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3) UNION or UNION ALL will show the same result.

I remember that I thought a lot on this case. And I took the conclusion of that!

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, I am reading again. 
"UNION" always will be more time than "UNION ALL" even if it is the same result?

Comment: @jorge_vicente . . . I'm pretty sure that no database optimizes `UNION` to remove the duplicate elimination.  Hence, it will be slower.  That is why you should be using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Perfect. I will try to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make use of CTE.

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 'GROUP1' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP2' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP3' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
)
select * from CTE WHERE LicenseCode > 7878
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the results in any order then all you need to do is just put an order by the statement for the last select in the union. It will by default sort the entire result for you. So it should have looked like this

```
SELECT 'GROUP1' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP2' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP3' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY YourColumnName
```

But Since here you also want to filter the records based on the column. Please try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 'GROUP1' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
    FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT 'GROUP2' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
    FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT 'GROUP3' AS GROUP, LicenseCode, Field2, Field3, Field4
    FROM TABLE
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        WHERE LicenseCode > 7878
            ORDER BY Your Columnname
```